# Lots of H17 Heroku Errors

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, heroku-postgres, sinatra-activerecord

I am working on a ruby project using sinatra, heroku, activerecord, and postgresql. I am consistantly getting this error:

```
2015-06-10T19:30:52.015492+00:00 heroku[router]: http_error="Invalid HTTP status line" at=error code=H17 desc="Poorly formatted HTTP response" method=POST path="/login" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=e5c29131-1c22-47d7-84a4-b1b51e4a3905 fwd="74.71.233.85" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=135ms status=503 bytes=862
```

I cannot find out how to fix it. If anyone needs any more information to fix it, I would be happy to provide it.

Comment: Can you log the entire HTTP response header your server creates for ``/login`` before its sent?

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: I am not familiar with Ruby, so I couldn't say, but in node.js you'd do something like ``console.log(JSON.stringify(res.headers));``

Comment: I do not know how to do that, but will look into it.

Comment: Have you tried reading the Heroku documentation [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h17-poorly-formatted-http-response)

Comment: I doesn't give any advise on how to fix the error, at least as far as I read. If you see something I didn't please let me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by just making some other irrelevant edits and pushing to heroku again which caused a dyno restart which is what I believe solved the problem. Now it works just fine. If anyone can come up with an explanation for this that would be much appreciated.

And if it could be added as an answer it would be accepted! I find this very weird.

Comment: sounds like `heroku restart` is what fixed it, not the irrelevant edits.

Comment: @BrettC Thats what I think too

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was happening with a POST request to which my dyno was not returning a response code. It was fixed by returning a valid response code, such as 200. For example:

```
post '/user/:user_id/favourites/:item_id' do

  [add the favourite, and if successful...]

  200

end
```